# Disable prompt "allow script/activex control to run"

Tags: security, group-policy, internet-explorer, quickbooks

We have a policy of disallowing scripts and ActiveX controls to run on in IE our network (instead opting to use Firefox) thereby skirting a number of security issues dating back to IE 6, but we recently decided to purchase QuickBooks, which requires IE, scripts, and ActiveX controls. We aren't about to change our Firefox policy now, but we do need to get IE to play nice with QuickBooks without reducing IE security in general. So far our set up is as follows:

**Trusted Sites Zone setting**

- Enable "Allow active scripting"
- Enable "Run ActiveX controls and plugins"

The remaining settings are not configured. I've set the same settings to "prompt" for the internet zone for testing purposes, and I put the following in the "Site to Zone Assignment List":

**Site to Zone Assignment List**

- *.intuit.com : 2
- *.quickbooks.com : 2
- *.intuitmarket.com : 2
- *.payroll.com : 2

This has eliminated the majority of issues we have with prompts while using QuickBooks, but we are still getting prompts on a number of screens, and I can't figure out what could be causing them. For example, [Quickbooks Forms Customization](https://intuitmarket.intuit.com/Customization/CC_Designs.aspx?ImprintID=13532321&Step=1&brand=3&track=52489&traffic=&fguid=) (I need to load the URL 2x before the forms page loads in IE) gives me both prompts:

- "Scripts are usually safe. Do you want to allow scripts to run?"
- "Do you want to allow software such as ActiveX controls and plug-ins to run?"

I've discussed the issue with QuickBooks support, but their support team was unhelpful. How can I get rid of the prompts?

Answer (score 1):

Well even if the site is in the trusted sites list, you need to either adjust the security setting: Tools>options>security settings> low/medium/high to allow scripts without warning. Click "custom" then look under the category of ActiveX controls. There's an option not to show warning for both previusly used and new scripts. That will resolve the "do you trust my script" error in IE.

Comment: "Allow previously unused ActiveX controls to run without prompt" is already set to Enable; I'm not sure what other option you are referring to.

Comment: I didn't know you had that set already. Are there any related options below it that may come in use in solving the issue? I really thought that would work.

Comment: What is the name of the other ActiveX control setting you mentioned? I couldn't find it, so I'm not sure what it's set to. It sounds like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, here's a bunch of screenshots of the menu: http://www.u4ik.us/public/activex.pdf